# File-dir returns no object

Tags: excel, vba

I need to loop through Excel files in a folder and erase a cell A1 on Cover sheet.
I found this code here on Stackoverflow.
Stepping through it shows that it's the 3rd line, file returns no object.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
file = Dir("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\BENCHMARKS\2. Scope files")

While (file <> "")
    Debug.Print Sheets("Cover").Cells(1, 1)
    file = Dir
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot your wildcard. `file = Dir("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\BENCHMARKS\2. Scope files\*.*")`

Comment: This code cannot do what you say that you need. Firstly, you must define file as a path plus an extension to be open by excel. Something like "C:\users\.....\" & "\*.xls*". Then, you must open the file during the `While` loop and check what you need for this opened file... Or loop between all files, but check the extension able to be open in Excel.

Comment: @braX, that fixed it, but i can't mark your comment as the answer.   Now i'll go research the rest of it, as FaneDuru was right, it doesn't work without opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot your wildcard.

```
file = Dir("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\BENCHMARKS\2. Scope files\*.*")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify which files you want to loop through, eg all Excel files. And you need to open, edit and save them in your loop.

Note that you need your path extra to be able to open the file, because `dir` only returns the file name without path, but you need both to be able to open it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\BENCHMARKS\2. Scope files\" 'needs to end with a backslash
    
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Dir(Path & "*.xls?") '*.xls? will accept all excel file formals: xls, xlsx, xlsm, xlsb, …

    While FileName <> vbNullString
        Debug.Print Path & FileName 'just to show which file we are currently on (can be removed)
        
        'open the workbook
        Dim OpenWb As Workbook
        Set OpenWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & FileName)
        
        'clear A1
        OpenWb.Worksheets("Cover").Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
        
        'save and close
        OpenWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        
        'next wb
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Note that this could benefit from some proper error handling which is not included yet.
Check out [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Comment: thanks a lot!   i selected braX' answer as that sorted out the first problem i had - no object. but yours is good and i'll use this. Thank you